# Reading chunks / streaming through a file with the FileChannel

Tags: java, nio

I am implementing some kind of file viewer/file explorer as a Web-Application. Therefore I need to read files from the hard disk of the system. Of course I have to deal with small files and large files and I want the fastest and most performant  way of doing this.

Now I have the following code and want to ask the "big guys" who have a lot of knowledge about efficiently reading (large) files if I am doing it the right way:

```
RandomAccessFile fis = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
FileChannel fileChannel = fis.getChannel();
// Don't load the whole file into the memory, therefore read 4096 bytes from position on
MappedByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, position, 4096);
byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (mappedByteBuffer.hasRemaining()) {
  // Math.min(..) to avoid BufferUnderflowException
  mappedByteBuffer.get(buf, 0, Math.min(4096, map1.remaining()));
  sb.append(new String(buf));
}
LOGGER.debug(sb.toString()); // Debug purposes
```

I hope you can help me and give me some advices.

Answer (score 0):

When you are going to view arbitrary files, including potentially large files, I’d assume that there’s possibility that these files are not actually text files or that you may encounter files which have different encodings.

So when you are going to view such files as text on a best-effort basis, you should think about which encoding you want to use and make sure that failures do not harm your operation. The constructor you use with `new String(buf)` does replace invalid characters, but it is redundant to construct a new `String` instance and append it to a `StringBuilder` afterwards.

Generally, you shouldn’t go so many detours. Since Java 7, you don’t need a `RandomAccessFile` (or `FileInputStream`) to get a `FileChannel`. A straight-forward solution would look like

```
// Instead of StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1 you could also use Charset.defaultCharset()
CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1.newDecoder()
    .onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    .onUnmappableCharacter(CodingErrorAction.REPLACE)
    .replaceWith(".");

try(FileChannel fileChannel=FileChannel.open(Paths.get(filename),StandardOpenOption.READ)) {
    //Don't load the whole file into the memory, therefore read 4096 bytes from position on
    ByteBuffer mappedByteBuffer = fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_ONLY, position, 4096);
    CharBuffer cb = decoder.decode(mappedByteBuffer);
    LOGGER.debug(cb.toString()); // Debug purposes
}
```

You can operate with the resulting `CharBuffer` directly or invoke `toString()` on it to get a `String` instance (but of course, avoid doing it multiple times). The `CharsetDecoder` also allows to re-use a `CharBuffer`, however, that may not have such a big impact on the performance. What you should definitely avoid, is to concatenate all these chunks to a big string.